# Button using pull-right in Bootstrap is touching the right edges

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML in my Laravel project View.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <a id="clear-schedule" class="btn btn-xs btn-raised pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 id="panel-title" class="panel-title">Classes
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="classes" class="panel-body panel-options">
    </div>
</div>
```

The id `clear-schedule` is a button that triggers an AJAX call to clear the cart, but that's not really important to the context of this question.

My question is: why is my button pulled so much to the right where it's touching the panel?

My other icons, which use `pull-right`, are fine.

[image]

This is what it looks like without `pull-right`:

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's because it should be in your `panel-heading` div, after your `<h3>` tag. Does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Someone may have a better answer, I'm not that experienced with html, but as a quick fix you can put the `a` tag inside your `h3` to get it to align with your `h3` tag after floating to the right.

Your `a` tag is outside the `panel-heading` block and is just inside the `panel` div.

`panel-heading`, `panel-body` etc all have different css properties that give them different paddings etc inside the panel div.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 id="panel-title" class="panel-title">Classes 
      <a id="clear-schedule" class="btn btn-xs btn-raised pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="classes" class="panel-body panel-options">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, put it before the `h3` tag.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a id="clear-schedule" class="btn btn-xs btn-raised pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <h3 id="panel-title" class="panel-title">Classes
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="classes" class="panel-body panel-options">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ZQlKVyaTOs)

Comment: I believe that will make it inherit the font-sizes though, right? I usually just add it after to avoid this.

Comment: Hey there! The alignment is fixed, but it eats into the bottom panel: http://puu.sh/oykiM/65c7cb2a3a.png

Comment: Good catch updated to include that as well! Html isn't a language I use a lot.

Comment: Me either, usually it's just lots of trial and error over here haha. :)

Comment: I just tried your code, and this is what I get: http://puu.sh/oym4A/a8d1b4e288.png Let me check if I have any external CSS causing the issue..

Comment: Doesn't seem like I have any thing causing any issues. This is so weird!

Answer (score 0):

## edit:

According to the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels), a panel consists of three optional parts: `panel-heading`, `panel-body` and `panel-footer`. Since the button you want to pull right is in the heading , you should put the HTML in the `panel-heading`

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a id="clear-schedule" class="btn btn-xs btn-raised pull-right">
           <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </a>
        <h3 id="panel-title" class="panel-title">Classes
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="classes" class="panel-body panel-options">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice: element with `.pull-left` or `.pull-right` should be put before `<h3>`

## css solution (original answer, not good):

Why not just add css to the button?

e.g.

```
<a id="clear-schedule" class="btn btn-xs btn-raised pull-right" style="margin-right:10px">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

or

```
<a id="clear-schedule" class="btn btn-xs btn-raised pull-right" style="position:relative;left:-10px">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

The better way to do it is to not use inline css, but add the css rules in .css file. Like in `style.css`

```
#clear-schedule
{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

or

```
#clear-schedule
{
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without extra CSS? I think I'm just using the HTML wrong.

Comment: Yeah you are right, it's indeed an issue with HTML. I overlooked the HTML part, I've modified my answer.